# Can we use AND and OR in a single findyBy method of Spring Data to access MonogDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have added a custom query method in the Mongo Repository Interface:

```
Employee findByFirstNameAndLastName(Stirng firstName, String lastName);
```

Which is returning Employees fulfilling the following criteria:

> // FirstName AND Last Name

Above method works really good, All thanks to Spring Data.

But, I want something like this:

```
Employee findByFirstNameAndLastNameOrDesignation(Stirng firstName, String lastName, String designation);
```

Above method should return Employee details as per following criteria:

> // FirstName AND (Last Name OR Designation)

**Is it possible to use AND and OR in a single method?**

Comment: Well, in this case you need a CustomRepository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although SpringData is powerful it is not so powerful. There is no way that SpringData know what you want:

1) A and (B or C)

or

2) (A and B) or C
etc...

You can use @NamedQuery or @Query.

Another option is to utilize Bool algebra. For example

A and (B or C) == (A and B)or (A and C)

so you can have method with following name: findByAandB_AandC.